# AngularJS 100 above records not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, sql-server, asp.net-ajax

c# code

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<RestaurantSubMenuDTO> GetRestaurantSubMenus()
{
    List<RestaurantSubMenuDTO> restaurantMenus = new List<RestaurantMenuDTO>();
    restaurantMenus = APIFactory.ORestaurantSubMenu.GetByCountryId(Utility.Misc.SelectedCountry_Admin, Utility.LanguageResource.LanguageId_Admin);
    return restaurantMenus;
}
```

angularjs code

```
function loadRestaurantSubMenus($rootScope, $scope, ajaxRequest, $timeout) {
    showWaiting();
    var request = ajaxRequest({
        method: "POST",
        url: "restaurantsubmenu.aspx/GetRestaurantSubMenus",
        data: {}
    });

    request.success(function (result) {
        $timeout(function () {
            console.log(result.d.Id);
            // alert(result.d);
            $scope.restaurantsubmenus = result.d;
            hideWaiting();
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

html code

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rsm in restaurantsubmenus | orderBy:sortKey:reverse | filter:search:strict">
        <td>{{ $index + 1}}</td>
        <td>
            <img ng-src="../images/restaurantmenu/{{rm.ImageURL}}" height="50px" width="50px" />
        </td>
        <td>{{rsm.MenuItem}}</td>
        <td>{{rsm.RestaurantName}}</td>
        <td>{{rsm.IsHidePrice}}</td>
        <td>{{rsm.SellingPrice}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="editRestaurantMenu(rsm)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="deleteRestaurantMenu(rsm.Id)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>Remove</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Hi, can you tell us, explicitly, what you're expecting and what's actually happening?

Comment: [WebMethod]
        public static List<RestaurantMenuDTO> GetRestaurantMenus()
        {
            List<RestaurantMenuDTO> restaurantMenus = new List<RestaurantMenuDTO>();
            restaurantMenus = APIFactory.ORestaurantMenu.GetByCountryId(Utility.Misc.SelectedCountry_Admin, Utility.LanguageResource.LanguageId_Admin);
            return restaurantMenus;
        }

Comment: the above code list all the records from my database

Comment: function loadRestaurantMenus($rootScope, $scope, ajaxRequest, $timeout) {
    showWaiting();
    var request = ajaxRequest({
        method: "POST",
        url: "restaurantmenu.aspx/GetRestaurantMenus",
        data: {}
    });

    request.success(function (result) {
        $timeout(function () {
            console.log(result.d.Id);
            // alert(result.d);
            showWaiting();
            $scope.restaurantmenus = result.d;
            hideWaiting();
        }, 0);
    });
}

Comment: this above code is angularjs code

Comment: the HTML code is there

Comment: But records not loaded, this is the problem, when the table have only 100 records it will show the 100 records but if i add more records to the table then its not showing any records

Comment: When you add more record are you refreshing/ recalling the api to get fresh list ?

Comment: No my friend if i refresh the page the records not come,

Comment: do you have any solution how to list all the records using angularjs